# Populate dataset with random amounts within nominated constraints

Tags: php, arrays, loops, random, constraints

I am trying to create a fantasy cricket team of 11 players from a large list of players.

For the team, I have basic minimum and maximum requirements for each type of player. I have assigned values like this:

```
$min_wicket_keeper = 1;
$min_batsman = 3;
$min_all_rounders = 1;
$min_bowlers = 2;

$max_wicket_keeper = 3;
$max_batsman = 5;
$max_all_rounders = 5;
$max_bowlers = 4;
```

I have total players like this:

```
$total_wicket_keepers = 2;
$total_batsman = 6;
$total_all_rounders = 5;
$total_bowlers = 5;
```

You can see I have total 18 players. Now I want to create a team of 11 players  assigning random type players -- keep in mind the minimum and maximum requirements of players.

Example 1

```
$wicket_keeper_limit = 1;
$batsman_limit = 4;
$all_rounder_limit = 4;
$bowler_limit = 2;
//so total 11
```

Example 2

```
$wicket_keeper_limit = 2;
$batsman_limit = 3;
$all_rounder_limit = 3;
$bowler_limit = 3;
//so total 11
```

I want a random number assigned for each type but total should be 11 and should not below minimum requirements and should not greater then total available players for each type followed by maximum limit.

I have tried code like this

```
$min_wicket_keeper = 1;
$min_batsman = 3;
$min_all_rounders = 1;
$min_bowlers = 2;

$max_wicket_keeper = 3;
$max_batsman = 5;
$max_all_rounders = 5;
$max_bowlers = 4;

$total_wicket_keepers = 2;
$total_batsman = 6;
$total_all_rounders = 5;
$total_bowlers = 5;


$total_players_match = $total_wicket_keepers+$total_batsman+$total_all_rounders+$total_bowlers;

echo $total_players_match;

if ($total_players_match > 11) {
    $remain_players = 11;
    if ($total_wicket_keepers > $min_wicket_keeper) {
        $wicket_keeper_limit = rand($min_wicket_keeper,$total_wicket_keepers);
        $remain_players = $remain_players-$wicket_keeper_limit;
    } else {
        $wicket_keeper_limit = $total_wicket_keepers;
        $remain_players = $remain_players-$wicket_keeper_limit;
    }
        
    echo "WK: ".$wicket_keeper_limit." REMAIN: ".$remain_players."<br>";
        
    if ($total_batsman>$min_batsman) {
        $batsman_limit = rand($min_batsman,$total_batsman);
        $remain_players = $remain_players-$batsman_limit;
            
        if ($remain_players > ($total_bowlers + $total_all_rounders)) {
            $batsman_limit = ($min_batsman + $remain_players) - ($total_bowlers+$total_all_rounders);
            $remain_players = $remain_players-$batsman_limit;
        }
            
    } else {
        $batsman_limit = $total_batsman;
        $remain_players = $remain_players-$batsman_limit;
    }
        
    echo "BT: " . $batsman_limit . " REMAIN: " . $remain_players . "<br>";
        
    if ($total_bowlers > $min_bowlers) {
        $bowler_limit = rand($min_bowlers, $total_bowlers);
        $remain_players = $remain_players - $bowler_limit;
            
        if ($remain_players > $total_all_rounders) {
            $bowler_limit = $total_bowlers;
            $remain_players = $remain_players - $bowler_limit;
        }

    } else {
            $bowler_limit = $total_bowlers;
        $remain_players = $remain_players - $bowler_limit;
    }
        
    echo "BOL:" . $bowler_limit . " REMAIN:" . $remain_players . "<br>";
        
    $all_rounder_limit = $remain_players;
        
    echo "ALL: " . $all_rounder_limit . " REMAIN: " . $remain_players . "<br>";
        
} else {
    $wicket_keeper_limit = $total_wicket_keepers;
    $batsman_limit = $total_batsman;
    $all_rounder_limit = $total_all_rounders;
    $bowler_limit = $total_bowlers;
}
    
echo "WK:" . $wicket_keeper_limit . "<br>";
    echo "BT:" . $batsman_limit . "<br>";
    echo "BO:" . $bowler_limit . "<br>";
    echo "AL:" . $all_rounder_limit . "<br>";
```

but it's failing to **follow my minimum and maximum requirements. Sometimes I am getting bowler as 0 and sometimes I am getting all rounder as high as 6.**

This is [Online Fiddle Link](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ztfg3vx2)

**Edit:** According to comments, I should clear that, I will generate multiple teams with put above code in while loops, Like 50 teams which will have different/random players in each type like some team have 5 batsman, some team will have only 3 batsman.

When I will get above code working, I will later get players from my database according to limit, I have got for each type.

Comment: I would expect a bunch of while loops to assign until your condition is met. Also you just work with numbers. Shouldn't you have an array of players to select from? I fail to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Wimanicesir When I will get SET of each type players with code, I will call mysql database for get that amount of players. I want players amount fixed at this stage, later, I will get players from database according to assigned players in each type.

Comment: Ok but your requirements are not so clear. I suppose you would like to fill the team with the minimum first and add one of each group until you have a full team. If a team consist of only playing people, why would you have two goalies? What difference is there between multiple teams?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I want multiple teams with random players thats why I want do like above I have said, some team will have 4 batsman and some team will have 5 batsman and so on for other type players.

Comment: But to be crystal clear. Some teams will have two goalies?

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Yes, since its fantasy team, I can have minimum 1 and maximum 3 goalies as I have assigned that minimum and maximum in my first set of code

Comment: didn't you ask a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466194/how-to-generate-team-using-php-mysql. Also i can you want to create teams as you mention, where are you storing a team when you create it?

Comment: @Adi, its different question. Its MYSQL based thing and this is related to PHP. I want more control like minimum and maximum players in each category defined. I will store teams in mysql database later after generating team. Thanks!

Comment: I tried a logic on your fiddle link and it seems to work, what you can do is initialize an array of team with all minimum number of each type of players, this way you would have 7 players by default, then just randomize, based on each player and check if the max limit is being reached or not and the total limit is not being exceeded. This approach requires a loop

Comment: Just for further clarifications, how many teams are you trying to create out of the total 18 players with each having 11?

Comment: @Adi I will create 100 teams in which I have different captains and vice captains.

Comment: @Mira that doesn't answer my question, how many teams are you trying to create out of the total 18 players with each having 11 players, in this question? So if we create one team 7 players will be left out of the total or if we create 2 teams, then players will be repeated and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might build this script as a single function/method or better would be to practice the single-responsibility principle and have multiple functions/methods which perform exactly one task. To avoid expanding the snippet too much, I'll only show my advice as a multi-responsibility function.

- Pass in your team creation settings.
- Implement logical guard conditions to alert you when settings prevent populating a full team.
- Apply the maximum limitations on your total player pool.
- As a shortcut, seed your team with all designated minimum values.
- Randomly select one position at a time in a loop and "consume" that position in the pool so that a position can never be over-drawn from the pool.
- When the team is full or the pool is empty, kill the loop.
- Return the populated team or alert the user if the team couldn't be fully populated.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fTeqPT))

```
function randomizeTeam(
    int $teamSize,
    array $positionPool,
    array $positionMins = [],
    array $positionMaxs = []
): array {
    // guard conditions
    foreach ($positionMins as $pos => $min) {
        if (!key_exists($pos, $positionPool) || $positionPool[$pos] < $min) {
            throw new Exception('Position pool cannot accommodate minimum required positions');
        }
    }

    // input preparation
    foreach ($positionMaxs as $pos => $max) {
        if (key_exists($pos, $positionPool) && $positionPool[$pos] > $max) {
            $positionPool[$pos] = $max;
        }
    }
    
    // seed team
    $team = [];
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($positionPool as $pos => &$pool) {
        $team[$pos] = $positionMins[$pos] ?? 0;
        $pool -= $team[$pos];
        if (!$pool) {
            unset($positionPool[$pos]); // remove exhausted pool
        }
        $sum += $team[$pos];
    }
    
    // add random positions
    while ($sum < $teamSize && $positionPool) {
        $pos = array_rand($positionPool);
        ++$team[$pos];
        --$positionPool[$pos];
        if (!$positionPool[$pos]) {
            unset($positionPool[$pos]); // remove exhausted pool
        }
        ++$sum;
    }

    // another guard condition
    if (array_sum($team) < $teamSize) {
        throw new Exception('Position pool was exhausted before filling team');
    }

    return $team;
}

var_export(
    randomizeTeam(
        11,
        [
            'wicket_keeper' => 2,
            'batsman'       => 6,
            'all_rounders'  => 5,
            'bowlers'       => 5,
        ],
        [
            'wicket_keeper' => 1,
            'batsman'       => 3,
            'all_rounders'  => 1,
            'bowlers'       => 2,
        ],
        [
            'wicket_keeper' => 3,
            'batsman'       => 5,
            'all_rounders'  => 5,
            'bowlers'       => 4,
        ]
    )
);
```

Potential output:

```
array (
  'wicket_keeper' => 2,
  'batsman' => 4,
  'all_rounders' => 2,
  'bowlers' => 3,
)
```

Some additional notes:

- It is ideal to declare your input data in array form so that you can enjoy the dynamic benefits of loops and array functions while avoiding variable variables.
- The above script is design to permit an extendable position pool and allow min and/or max position constraints which do not need to mention all positions in the master pool.